# Crusader Kings 2 trait modding "birth" and "inherit_chance" attributes

Tags: mods, crusader-kings-2

If you create a trait with birth = 0 and inherit_chance = 100, does that effectively create a trait that only your ancestors can have?

In other words does the inherit_chance attribute take precedence over the birth attribute?

```
birth- Given number out of every 10000 characters born will receive this trait, (e.g., 100 = 1%)    

inherit_chance- A newborn can inherit the trait from a parent (optional); if both parents have the trait, uses two trials of same chance
```

Comment: I would think that the Sayyid trait works along the lines of what you susggest. It never appears at random and is always inherited from a Sayyid father. The only notable difference is that Sayyid mothers instead pass on the Mirza trait to their children, unless there is a Sayyid father.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the files were updated in a recent DLC, but the **00_traits.txt** file (in common folder) now suggests that **inherit_chance** is applied before the generic **birth**, and would therefore take precedence.

```
# inherit_chance = X    - Chance of passing on the trait to children
# birth = X             - How many characters out of 10000 are born with this trait (when not inherited)
```

Anecdotally, **syphilitic** has an value for **inherit_chance**, and no **birth** value, and I have seen it be inherited. This does seem to be what you want.